# Heatmap annotation with value and colour gradient

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to use ComplexHeatmap to plot heatmap with annotation. 
The code that I  have tried

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)
mat = matrix(rnorm(25), 5)
rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:5)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:5)

col_fun = colorRamp2(c(0, 2, 5), c("white", "blue", "red"))
data_foo = c(0.1, 3, 1.6, 2.8, 4)

ha = HeatmapAnnotation(which = "row", foo = data_foo, col = list(foo = col_fun))
Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", right_annotation = ha)

ha1 = HeatmapAnnotation(which = "row", foo = anno_text(data_foo))
Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", right_annotation = ha1)
```

Can I obtain the annotation with colors varying as per the annotation values and also display the values in the annotation? i.e is it possible to combine the annotation in both figures?
[image: HeatMap with color annotation]

[image: HeatMap with values as annotation]

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @haci, converted from comment:*

You can use the `pch` parameter in `anno_simple()` but you can only use a single character or a digit. It is not limited to symbols only,  you can provide a vector to `pch`, but only the first character would be printed. If by chance your values are [0-9] you can use `pch` as kind of hack for your purposes above.